# Representation of Weyl-Heisenberg Lie Algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

I'm reading the book: Coherent State in Quantum Physics, by Jean-Pierre Gazeau. In the page no. 35 of this book, the Weyl-Heisenberg Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{w}_m$ has been given that
$$\mathfrak{w}_m=linear\,span\{iQ,iP,iI_d\};$$ where $Q=\frac{a+a^\dagger}{\sqrt{2}}$, $P=\frac{a-a^\dagger}{i\sqrt{2}}$ and $I_d$ is the identity operator with $a$ is annihilation operator and $a^\dagger$ is creation operator. One can see that a generic element of $\mathfrak{w}_m$ is written as 
$$\mathfrak{w}_m\ni X=isI_d+i(pQ-qP)=isI_d+(za^\dagger-\overline{z}a);$$ where $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z=\frac{q+ip}{\sqrt{2}}$. Here $X$ is the anti-self-adjoint and the infinitesimal generator of the unitary operator:
$$e^X = e^{is}e^{za^\dagger-\overline{z}a}:=e^{is}D(z).$$ After this some discussion on the action of the D-Function. My question is, in the page no. 37, it is said that the map $X\longmapsto e^X=e^{is}D(z)$ is *irreducible unitary representation* of Weyl-Heisenberg Algebra, but first of all it, to say this map $X\longmapsto e^X=e^{is}D(z)$ is representation of Weyl-Heisenberg Algebra, I think it should satisfy the relation 
$$e^{[X,Y]}=[e^X,e^Y],$$ for all $X,Y \in \mathfrak{w}_m$, since it is Lie algebra. But I'm unable to obtain this relation. Could anyone please help me...!!! I'm looking for a explanation. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273773/2451 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/247292/13917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M. Tharan

First I am grateful to you for reading my 2009 book and to help me to clarify some points in its content. Actually, what is written in page 37 is exactly the following

*The operators X, **through** the map $X \mapsto e^X = e^{is}D(z)$, **thus** define an irreducible unitary representation of the Weyl–Heisenberg algebra $\mathfrak{w}$.*

I did not write that the map itself **is** a representation of the algebra.

I wished to mean that the representation of the algebra itself comes from infinitesimal generators of the representation of the group. In an updated version I will improve  that  sentence in order to make the point clearer. Thank you again!

More informations are given in the recent arXiv:1703.08443v1 [quant-ph]

*WEYL-HEISENBERG INTEGRAL QUANTIZATION(S): A COMPENDIUM*

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, for taking your precious time to clarify it.  I can well understand your busy schedule, and appreciate the effort you have taken for writing back. The arXiv document is very useful to me. Thank you so much.